# Insert the first element in an array

Tags: c

I am trying to insert the new element in an array in the first position. For example, in the array [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] I would like to add one more element in the first position and want the outout as [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]. Here is what I have tried:

```
for (j=0; j< sizeof(array); j++){
  array[j+1] = array[j];
 }
  array[0] =0;
```

But the ouput looks like [0,1,1,1....]. Pleased to hear some suggestions.

Comment: Please show a [mcve]. `sizeof(array)` is most likely wrong.

Comment: Increase the size of the array. And iterate from the size of array to zero i.e., n to 0.

Comment: BTW: your output should look like this: [0, 1, 1, 1, ...]. The code you show can hardly produce the result you show.

Comment: @Jabberwocky - Thanks for the comment. I have posted it wrong.

Comment: @ali so what are you waiting for [edit]ing your question?

Answer (score 2):

You need to start from ending of an array.

This will help you:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

    int array[5] = {1, 2, 3, 4};

    for (int j = sizeof(array)/sizeof(int) - 1; j >0 ; j--) {
        array[j] = array[j-1];
    }
    array[0] = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(array)/sizeof(int); i++)
        printf("%d\n", array[i]);


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But, there is problem in the output with your answer. The second element is missing. I get the output as [0,1,3,4,5]. Pleased to hear some suggestions.

Comment: The output is must be correct. (I checked it) I think your mistake is: 5th line of code: you need to write `int array[6] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};` if you want an array with 5 elements at the beginning.

Comment: The code is correct! The only thing you could improve is replacing the `sizeof(int)` with `sizeof(array[0])` to be independent from the size of the array elements.

Answer (score 1):

You have to start from end, else you're replacing next values.

```
for(i=10;i>0;i--){
    myarray[i]=myarray[i-1];
}
myarray[0]=0;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to start from the end

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    unsigned char array[5] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

    for (int j = sizeof(array) - 1; j > 0; j--) {
        array[j] = array[j - 1];
    }

    array[0] = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(array); ++i) {
        printf("%d ", array[i]);
    }

    printf("\n");
}
```